# How to set stickerSize in MSStickerBrowserViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mssticker

When I create a MSStickerBrowserViewController subclass by embedding it in a container view (using a storyboard) as the documentation suggests, I appear to have no opportunity to set the stickerSize. The Sticker Browser VC is initialized with init(coder:), and I have no way that I can see to override the get-only property stickerSize. I can only get stickerSize = MSStickerSize.regular.

I don't see any control in interface builder to configure the property either, though the documentation says "You can also customize the size of the stickers inside the browser."

Thanks to shallowThought, I see that an initializer is available init(stickerSize: MSStickerSize) on MSStickerBrowserViewController, but so far I have been unable to find a way to trigger that initializer when using a storyboard and overriding the required init(coder:) initializer.

Am i missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the the code you have tried to make others see and better understand what your issue is in regards to the initializers.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me: I added `stickerSize` to the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" section of the Identity Inspector.

In this example, PetStickerBrowserViewController is a subclass of `MSBrowserStickerViewController`. `stickerSize` is set to 0, which corresponds to `MSStickerSize.small`.

At runtime, when the view controller is instantiated from the storyboard, its `stickerSize` property is set to `.small`. Use 1 for `.regular` (the default), and 2 for `.large`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set it when initializing.

From [Apples documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages)

**StickerBroweserView**

```
init(frame: CGRect, stickerSize: MSStickerSize)
```

> Creates a new sticker browser containing stickers of the specified size.

**StickerBroweserViewController**

```
init(stickerSize: MSStickerSize)
```

> Creates a new sticker browser view controller with stickers of the provided size.

To subclass it, implement the corresponding `init`ializers.

I can not see a way to call `init(stickerSize: MSStickerSize)` by somehow chaining `init` calls from `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, so you might have to instantiate the viewControllers programmatically.

Comment: Welcome. On SO we thank by upvoting / accepting answers.

Comment: One thing: When I instantiate from a storyboard init(coder:) is used, so I am not able to call init(stickerSize:). If I override init(stickerSize:) in my MSStickerBrowserViewController subclass, and set a breakpoint I see that that initializer never runs. Any thoughts?

I may have to set it up programmatically rather than using the storyboard to avoid triggering init(coder:)?

Comment: Hi I did just upvote, but SO informed me that the upvote will not show publicly until I gain more rep on SO :-) And still looking for how to trigger init(stickerSize:) while using storyboard, so I haven't marked accepted just yet. Really do appreciate it!

Comment: All good :-). Regarding init(coder:: That is a good question. I am afraid you have to set it up programmatically, but I am not sure right now if it is possible to create a initializer chain from `required` ` init(coder:` up to `super.init(stickerSize:`. I can not try in the moment. Append this to your question, maybe someone else helps you faster.